# Where should I ask a question about teaching English as a 2nd language

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I have a question about teaching English as a second language. Is there any Stack Exchange website on which this question can be asked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can ask such questions on [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> English Language Learners Stack Exchange is for people who are learning **or teaching English as a foreign language**.

Emphasis mine.

Please do study their help center, specifically what [the site considers on-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what to avoid asking about](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Thanks Martijin. Shows how lazy I am for not reading the documentation. Not yet allowed to accept answer. Will do in about 15 minutes or so.